Invalid configuration for nameservers
I have an issue with my domains configuration in Vercel hosting. It told me something like this:
Set the nameservers of cigindonesia.com (apex domain) to:
ns1.vercel-dns.com
ns2.vercel-dns.com

Current nameservers:
dns10.parkpage.foundationapi.com
dns11.parkpage.foundationapi.com
ns1.vercel-dns.com
ns2.vercel-dns.com

I don't think I'm able to remove these 2 nameservers:
dns10.parkpage.foundationapi.com
dns11.parkpage.foundationapi.com

What am I doing wrong?
In the panel where the domain is bought, it says something like this:

Which translates directly to Nameserver has been changed!

Why do you think you can't remove those two nameservers? Based on the name, they're related to a domain parking page.

In the place where the domain is bought, it just says that the 2 nameservers has been changed successfully.

See if there's a separate option to disable the parking page, maybe.
